# ERROR Invalid config, exiting abnormally in Kafka cluster

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I have three different nodes that every one has docker with Ubuntu on it. I can run zookeeper server on docker locally (I mean without any configuration for cluster), but I want to make kafka cluster with these three nodes; In fact, I installed docker on each node with loading Ubuntu with on them. I configure `"zookeeper.properties"` in docker environment for "150.20.11.157" like this:

```
dataDir=/tmp/zookeeper/data
tickTime=2000
initLimit=10
syncLimit=5
server.1=0.0.0.0:2888:3888
server.2=150.20.11.134:2888:3888
server.3=150.20.11.137:2888:3888
clientPort=2186
```

For node 150.20.11.134, "zookeeper.properties" file in docker environment is like this:

```
dataDir=/tmp/zookeeper/data
tickTime=2000
initLimit=10
syncLimit=5
server.1=150.20.11.157:2888:3888
server.2=0.0.0.0:2888:3888
server.3=150.20.11.137:2888:3888
clientPort=2186
```

For node 150.20.11.137, "zookeeper.properties" file in docker environment is like this:

```
dataDir=/tmp/zookeeper/data
tickTime=2000
initLimit=10
syncLimit=5
server.1=150.20.11.157:2888:3888
server.2=150.20.11.134:2888:3888
server.3=0.0.0.0:2888:3888
clientPort=2186
```

Also, I setup "server.properties" like this, for node 150.20.11.157:

```
broker.id=0
port=9092
listeners = PLAINTEXT://150.20.11.157:9092
log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs 
zookeeper.connect=150.20.11.157:2186,150.20.11.134:2186,
150.20.11.137:2186
```

"server.properties" for node 150.20.11.134 is:

```
broker.id=1
port=9092
listeners = PLAINTEXT://150.20.11.134:9092
log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs 
zookeeper.connect=150.20.11.157:2186,150.20.11.134:2186,
150.20.11.137:2186
```

"server.properties" for node 150.20.11.137 is:

```
broker.id=2
port=9092
listeners = PLAINTEXT://150.20.11.137:9092
log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs 
zookeeper.connect=150.20.11.157:2186,150.20.11.134:2186,
150.20.11.137:2186
```

The problem is when I run zookeeper server on docker of each node. I get this error:

```
[2019-01-16 12:45:54,588] INFO Reading configuration from: ./config/zookeeper.properties 
(org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig)

[2019-01-16 12:45:54,601] INFO Resolved hostname: 172.28.10.137 to address: /172.28.10.137 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeer)

[2019-01-16 12:45:54,603] INFO Resolved hostname: 0.0.0.0 to address: /0.0.0.0 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeer)

[2019-01-16 12:45:54,603] INFO Resolved hostname: 172.28.10.157 to address: /172.28.10.157 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeer)

[2019-01-16 12:45:54,603] INFO Defaulting to majority quorums (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig)

[2019-01-16 12:45:54,604] ERROR Invalid config, exiting abnormally (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain)

org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig$ConfigException: Error processing ./config/zookeeper.properties
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig.parse(QuorumPeerConfig.java:156)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.initializeAndRun(QuorumPeerMain.java:104)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.main(QuorumPeerMain.java:81)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: /tmp/zookeeper/data/myid file is missing
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig.parseProperties(QuorumPeerConfig.java:408)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig.parse(QuorumPeerConfig.java:152)    
... 2 more

Invalid config, exiting abnormally
```

Would you please tell me how to have a Kafka cluster with three docker that each docker is on one physical node?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've run into this too.

I think the clue for this one is in the logs i.e.

> **Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:**
>   **/tmp/zookeeper/data/myid file is missing at**
>   org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig.parseProperties(QuorumPeerConfig.java:408)

The following lines in your `zookeeper.properties` file provide the details of the zookeeper ensemble:

```
server.1=0.0.0.0:2888:3888
server.2=150.20.11.134:2888:3888
server.3=150.20.11.137:2888:3888
```

When one of the zookeeper server starts, it knows which server it is by looking at the `myid` file in it's own data directory, which in this case would be `/tmp/zookeeper/data`.

So, all you need to do is just create a file with the name `myid` in the above mentioned directory of each server and write just x = `1`, `2` or `3` (these correspond to server.`x` in the zookeeper.properties file).

Reference link - [Apache Zookeeper](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.3.3/zookeeperAdmin.html).

Hope this helps!